# Search query with newline for textarea data

Tags: php, mysql, html

i was using a input tag for entering the address in the form.

Input form code :

```
<input type="text" name="address">
```

and the search query for searching the addresses, worked without any problem

Search form code:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="category_address" value="address"/>
    <select name='criteria_address'">
        <option selected="selected"> </option>
    <?php
        $order = "SELECT DISTINCT address FROM lh_clients ORDER BY clientname" or die (mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query($order);  
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         echo ("<option> $data[address] </option>");
        }
    ?>
```

Search Result Display code :

```
if(isset($_POST['criteria_address']))
{
$category_address = $_POST['category_address'];
    $criteria_address = $_POST['criteria_address'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM lh_clients WHERE $category_address LIKE '%".$criteria_address."%'";

echo "<tr><td colspan='8'>$num_rows Results Found</td></tr>";
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo("<tr>
        <td>$data[clientname]</td>
        <td>$data[clienttype]</td>
    <td>$data[address]</td>
    <td>$data[contacts]</td>
    <td>$data[sensitivity]</td>
    <td>$data[acountmanager]</td>
    <td>$data[responsibleexecutive]</td>
    </tr>");
}
```

But now when i replacing the input tag and using  tag instead of it

textarea code :

```
<textarea name="address"></textarea>
```

The Search code doesn't work. The  tag works fine, it pop up data from the address column but doesn't providing any search result according to that address.

By the way, when i give input something with out entering newline it works.
If any one can understand my problem please reply.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: And [reading this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) about SQL injection will give you another reason to change !

Comment: ok....i will take care of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you put a newline in your searchword, you only gettings rows with that have that newline stored in the database.

1.
if an adress is stored in the database like
"`street 1, 123 45 town`",
and you try to search it by writing
"`street 1`
`123 45 town`"
they not going to match, you may want to replace newlines with `%` to allow other seperators.

2.
if you adress is stored in the database like `street 1`, and your search for
"`street 1`
"
then you may want to use `trim()` on the searchword to get rid of extra newlines

3.
to avoid carage return problem, you can use `REPLACE`

```
SELECT *
FROM lh_clients
WHERE
  REPLACE(adress, '\r', '') LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(:adress, '\r', ''), '%');
```

where `:adress` should be bind/replaced with the input variable

Comment: Actually I want that the address is stored in db with newline. And when i search for it (with <select> <option>) the address showing up exactly the same face, i was entered in the text field with newline. @Puggan Se

Comment: Then its can be a Carage Return character ("\r", CR, 0x13) besides your newline/line feed character ("\n", LF, 0x10), linux mostly use just "\n", windows mostly use "\r\n" and think mac use "\r" for new lines

Comment: @PugganSe Macs ever since OSX have used unix style "\n". But you are right, I'd guess it's "\r\n" vs "\n" that's messing up the search.

Comment: Excuse me, could you elaborate it please, I can't understand. @Puggan

Comment: if you want to store: A, newline, A, it can be stored as 3 bytes: "A\nA" = 0x410A41, or as 4 bytes: "A\r\nA" = 0x410D0A41, to the eye they look alike, but digitaly comparing the 3 byte text with the 4 byte text dosn't match

Comment: Yes, i understand that, but here in this case how can i implement this type of things. (Please don't mind i am little bit slow....)